# Change title in the application.html.slim based on the controller action name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I want to change and set custom title base on the controller action in the application.html.slim, not in the controller

```
- if controller.action_name=~"home"
  title Custom title here
- elsif controller.action_name=~"login"
  title Login Page
- else 
  Default title
```

But it's not working. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `=~` you'll need a regex on the right hand side, not a string.

```
- if controller.action_name =~ /home/
  title Home
- elsif controller.action_name =~ /login/
  title Login
- else
  title Default
```

However the method I normally use is to create entries in the translation file, `config/locales/en.yml` probably in your case and put the page titles there. If there is no entry, it falls back to the default you provide.

```
en:
  page_titles:
    welcome:
      index: Welcome
      login: Login
```

And then either directly in the view or create a helper function.

```
title= I18n.t("page_titles.#{controller.controller_name}.#{controller.action_name}", default: "Default title")
```